# BasicThreadPool Unavailable In J-boss 7.1

Tags: java, threadpool, jboss7.x

Apparently it's not supposed to be according to [How to get a MBean binding class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177710/how-to-get-a-mbean-binding-class-instance) . Yet one can compile with it, so I suspect it may just be a class-loading issue with J-boss 7.

Anyone know how to use BTP with J-boss 7 or a better thread pool implementation: Java.util.concurrent, Servlets (for non-HTTP), something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that using an `ExecutorService` is not an option?

See [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). I would suggest something like `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` or `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`.