# how to get register MBean with method getPlatformMXBean()?

Tags: java, jmx

I have register mbean by using

```
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(mbean, name);
```

And I can see this mbean in jconsole. I want get it by `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(mbean)`, but it throws Exception

> mbean not a platform management interface.

How can I get this registered bean?

Below is the code.

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Registering MBean...");
    try {
        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("common.test:type=MbeanTestImplement");
        MbeanTestInterface mbean = new MbeanTestImplement();
        ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(mbean, name);
        MbeanTestImplement mxbean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(MbeanTestImplement.class);
        System.out.println(mxbean.getName());
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //ManagementFactory.getMBeanserverConnection()
}
```

MbeanTestInterface extends PlatformManagedObject, and MbeanTestImplement implement MbeanTestInterface.

```
public interface MbeanTestInterface extends PlatformManagedObject {
    public String getName();
}

public class MbeanTestImplement implements MbeanTestInterface {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return MbeanTestImplement.class.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectName getObjectName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your MBean.

Comment: @hbelmiro Thanks, I pasted my code.

Comment: @NyxLuck I am not JMX guy, but is there a possibility that registerMBean(mbean, name)` is registering it an `MBean` instead of `MXBean` as the method name is indicating? On a different note, if intent is to get the `name` attribute of your `MXBean` you can try `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getAttribute(new ObjectName("common.test:type=MbeanTestImplement"), "Name")`

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Thanks for your concern. The MXBean are just a special kind of MBean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the MBean instance. But you can get its attributes and invoke its methods. You can also get an `javax.management.ObjectInstance` using this method:

```
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getObjectInstance(name)
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9177832/3245762).