# Get Tomcat's HTTP Executor instance

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

In our project we do some monitoring for different instances of `ThreadPoolExecutor`s from inside the code and that would be convenient to fetch (not as a JMX bean, but the real instance) Tomcat's HTTP NIO executor and treat it the same way we treat the rest of the executors. Can it probably be done?

As an example of the way it could be done: [Fetching JBoss ThreadPool instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9177832/1828937)

Apache Tomcat version: 8.5.15

Comment: And what is issue with JMX?

Comment: @rkosegi Well while I actually can extract the interesting values I can't work with it like I do with the bunch of the other executors, that's why I need a real instance, which can be probably possible with JMX, but I can't see how